# Jquery Header add class on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, header

I´m trying to add a hover function which adds a class to my header. I already got this code which does the same but on scroll.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(window).trigger('resize').trigger('scroll');

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll >= 1 ) {
        header.removeClass('scroll').addClass("cover");
        $('#phantom').show();
        $('#phantom').css('height', Heightcalculate+'px');
             } else {
        header.removeClass("cover").addClass('scroll');
        $('#phantom').hide();
      }
    });
```

Is there a way to edit this existing code so it does the same but on hover? i tried everything i could think of and it wouldn´t work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) function?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Try `$("elemnt").hover()`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all of your code, it's hard to tell you exactly what to do, but this is the general idea using jQuery's `$.hover()`. Apply the class on hover, and optionally remove the class when you hover off.

```js
$('header').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('class');
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('class');
});
```

```css
.class {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>header</header>
```

Comment: i already tried this... doesn´t work.

Comment: @Geatrix then you need to give us a working demo so we can give you more accurate code that will work for you. Otherwise we're just taking guesses.

Comment: I can´t, because i´m using shopify and im editing a theme that isn´t active and only i can preview it. should i send you the header.liquid file?